# C# AzureSDK SecretClient how to authenticate against AzureChinaCloud

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-sdk, azure-china

I am trying to get some secrets from a KeyVault in ***AzureChinaCloud***. I have the following code that is working fine for an ***AzureCloud*** KeyVault, however when I change the KeyVault address to one in China it no longer works.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Azure.Core;
using System;
namespace maintenance.connections
{
    public class AzureKeyVault
    {
        private const Int64 Delay = 2;
        private const Int64 MaxDelay = 16;
        private const Int32 MaxRetries = 5;
        private SecretClientOptions Options { get; set; }
        public SecretClient Secrets { get; set; }
        public AzureKeyVault(Uri VaultUrl)
        {
            Options = new SecretClientOptions();
            Options.Retry.Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Delay);
            Options.Retry.MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MaxDelay);
            Options.Retry.MaxRetries = MaxRetries;
            Options.Retry.Mode = RetryMode.Exponential;
            DefaultAzureCredentialOptions CredentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions();
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AuthorityHost") != null)
            {
                CredentialOptions.AuthorityHost = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AuthorityHost")); //AuthorityHost = https://login.chinacloudapi.cn/
            }
            Secrets = new SecretClient(VaultUrl, new DefaultAzureCredential(CredentialOptions), Options);
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute Secrets.GetSecret(SecretName) I get the following error

> AADSTS90002: Tenant 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' not found.
> Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID and are signing into
> the correct cloud. Check with your subscription administrator, this
> may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant.

Do you know what I am missing? The TenanId exist and the credentials set on environment variables has permissions.

Comment: Are you setting the `AZURE_TENANT_ID` environment variable used by `DefaultAzureCredential`?

Comment: Yes, I have the following environment variables set AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET. Also I tried it directly from and Azure Function in China configured to use a SystemManaged Identity and the same error is displayed

Comment: Hello, unless you are ok sharing your tenant id please post your answer in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-active-directory.html so that we can handle it privately.

Comment: Hello again, do you still need help?

Comment: yes, I do. I post a question in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/857908/c-azuresdk-secretclient-how-to-authenticate-agains.html, but still unsolved